# Default 'using' in Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to set 'using' as default in model? So will not always call it on views

```
list = OtherModel.objects.using("hede").all()
```

I tried like this. But not work :(

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    using = 'hede'
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) to achieve this. Check the documentation of [Automatic database routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)